# Solving integral involving absolute value by residue theorem

Tags: absolute-value, residue-calculus, complex-integration

How can I use the residue theorem to evaluate the following integral
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^{1/2}}{(x-4i)(x+2i)}dx $$
I think my trouble is in handling the absolute value. Should something special be done about it and is there a general way to do that?

Comment: Personally, I'd consider$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt x}{(x-4i)(x+2i)}~dx+\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\sqrt{-x}}{(x-4i)(x+2i)}~dx$$ if you aren't comfortable with the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well but still get an inconsistent result when I use the residue theorem on a larger curve integral that includes the one I'm trying to calculate. Essentially, depending on whether I close the curve in the upper or lower half plane I get different answers.